Hover mermaid node to have color changed
Is there a way to change node color when hover a node in mermaid flowchart? I know clickable node with tooltips but don’t see a way to have color changed. Many thanks in advance!
I tried many times with styling css but didn’t find a way.
Here is the code
<style>
.myId > rect {
    fill: red!important;
}
.myId:hover {
    fill: green!important;
    pointer-events: all;
}
</style>

```mermaid
flowchart LR
    A:::myId--> B
```


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
